# Gsutil copy/move files in batches

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Is there a way to copy or move files using gsutil command in batches?
For example If I want to copy 100 files from given folder to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
gsutil ls gs://bucketA | head -n 100 | shuf | gsutil cp -m -I gs://bucketB
```

This will get a listing of files from bucketA, take the first 100 items, randomize them with [`shuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf), and pipe them into `gsutil` to copy to bucketB. The `-I` flag reads the file list from `stdin`.

Comment: I think the -m flag needs to be before the cp command here.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is using the [Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries). For example in Python:

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()

bucket_name = 'my_bucket'
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

blobs_to_move = [blob for blob in bucket.list_blobs(prefix="folder1/")]

with storage_client.batch():
    for blob in blobs_to_move[:100]:
        # copy to new destination
        new_blob = bucket.copy_blob(blob, bucket, "folder2/" + blob.name[8:])
        # delete in old destination
        blob.delete()
```

This will move the first 100 files from the `folder1` in the GCS bucket `my_bucket` to `folder2`.

Comment: Not exactly. What I am looking for is a way to copy only subset of the whole content. For example only 100 files out of 1000.

Comment: Yes, randomly something that the find command does like here - find . -maxdepth 1 -type f |head -500|xargs

Comment: You can generate a list of files on your own and pipe them into gsutil using the `-I` flag.

Comment: @user101010 You can also do it using the Python client library. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification so it will randomly move 100 files instead of first 100 files from bucketA to bucketB:

```
gsutil ls gs://bucketA | shuf | head -n 100 | gsutil -m mv  -I gs://bucketB
```